# variable declared inside document ready not accessible in Jquery event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var ay = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ax = 0;
    $(document).on("click", "a[href$=#icom_add_to_cart]", function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(ax); // not accessible
        console.log(ay); // accessible
}
```

Please help me understand why ax is not accessible and ay is accessible inside onclick eventhandler.
I have a variable which I have to access inside multiple onclick handlers which are inside document.ready. How should be the best practice to declare this variable.
[image: Chrome console source]

[image: prods is available but catIds is not at the location of debug]

As you can see at debug location 'prods' is available but 'catIds' is coming as undefined.

Comment: — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Working fine for...     `var ay = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ax = 0;
  $(document).on("click", "a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(ax); // accessible
    console.log(ay); // accessible
  });
});`

Comment: it's not conosole, it's console

Comment: @Rayon When I click on the "add to cart" button after page load that time above eventhandler is called. At that time I am not able to access ax. Will share a executable snippet link.

Comment: Well in that case, selector does not select that element, check the criteria of that element to be selected by specified selector! `event.preventDefault();` will not make it reload!

Comment: [see the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qy3t1e6m/) .its working

Answer (score 2):

Aside from not closing your script with `});` it works ok, although I didn't understand your anchors, so I changed them in the Snippet.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var az = 3
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ax = 2;
  var ay = 1;
  $(document).on("click", "a[href^=#add]", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(ax);
    console.log(ay);
    console.log(az);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href='#add1'>+1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#add2'>+2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#add3'>+3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#add4'>+4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#add5'>+5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's strange, it's working fine for me

```
var ay = 5;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ax = 6;
    $(document).on("click", "html", function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(ax); // accessible
        alert(ay); // accessible
    })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqn2t9bs/